# ActionChains in Selenium not clicking button (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to use ActionChains to click a button with
python but it just refuses to work no matter what I do.

The issue is that whenever the website opens, it opens with an overlay.
I want my program to click the 'OK' button on the overlay. Whatever code I write just ends up clicking the overlay itself.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

URL = 'https://sam.gov/search/?index=opp&page=1&sort=-relevance&sfm%5Bstatus%5D%5Bis_active%5D=true&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueSelect%5D=customDate&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueFrom%5D=05%2F29%2F2021&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueTo%5D=05%2F29%2F2022&sfm%5Bkeywords%5D%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=541511&sfm%5Bkeywords%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=541511'

driver.get(URL)

overlay = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cdk-overlay-0")
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.usa-button")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(overlay).click(button).perform()
```

And the relevant HTML from the webpage I'm looking at is:

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" ...>
```

for the overlay, and

```
<button class="usa-button">OK</button>
```

for the button itself.

My code always ends up clicking just on the overlay and not the button. It ends up looking like this (the overlay gets a blue outline when clicked):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
URL = 'https://sam.gov/search/?index=opp&page=1&sort=-relevance&sfm%5Bstatus%5D%5Bis_active%5D=true&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueSelect%5D=customDate&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueFrom%5D=05%2F29%2F2021&sfm%5Bdates%5D%5BresponseDue%5D%5BresponseDueTo%5D=05%2F29%2F2022&sfm%5Bkeywords%5D%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=541511&sfm%5Bkeywords%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=541511'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'/html/body/div/div[2]/div/sds-dialog-container/layout-splash-modal/div[4]/div[2]/div/button').click()
```

I just used the xpath and clicked it without actionchains